# How many n-element subsets of real numbers are there

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to express the cardinality of all n-element subsets of real numbers.

Comment: you think that number is countable

Comment: What if $n=1$ ?

Comment: Then the cardinality is continuum.

Comment: @Anna: ok, so it is at least continuum for the general case. Now, can you write any $n$-element subset of $\Bbb R$ through its coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by subset's coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $[{\bf R}]^n$ be the set of $n$-element subsets of $\mathbf R$. Assumming $n > 0$, we have $|[{\bf R}]^n| \ge |{\bf R}| = 2^{\aleph_0}$. Conversely the map $f \colon [\mathbf R]^n \to \mathbf R^n$ defined by $f(\{x_1, ..., x_n\}) = (x_1, ..., x_n)$ where $x_1 < ... < x_n$ is injective. So $|[\mathbf R]^n| \le |\mathbf R^n| = |\mathbf R|^n = |\mathbf R| = 2^{\aleph_0}$. Thus $|[\mathbf R]^n| = 2^{\aleph_0}$.